# How we can extend Varien_File_Csv class in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, extend

I want to open CSV file in a+ mode for append content. I open Varien_File_Csv class and check for that but I did not found any option for open file in a+ mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "drop-in" trick.

Copy it in: `app/code/community/Varien/File/Csv.php` and change it according to your needings.

**BEWARE:** It will have system-wide effects, so make sure you are not making anything disruptive.

Otherwise you could use `Varien_Io_File`.
See methods:

- `streamOpen` (param `$mode`)
- `streamReadCsv`
- `streamWriteCsv`

Comment: Is there any another solution?

Comment: See my updated post